# How to prevent from scrolling Advanced DataGrid item after click event?

Tags: apache-flex

When I am double clicking in a cell of selected row in Adv DataGrid then an Alert comes up with ok button and when click on OK button the previously selected row deselects and first row of datagrid shown highlighted.

Comment: Could you provide some code of this problem? It's a good habit to share some code snippets which helps to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Import the Close Event if you haven't.

```
import mx.events.CloseEvent;
```

Create a variable to hold the selectedIndex:

```
[Bindable]
public var idindex:int = new int();
```

In the double click event get the selectedIndex of the advanced datagrid.

```
protected function adg1_doubleClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
idindex = adg1.selectedIndex;
Alert.show("Double clicked here.", "Test Title", Alert.OK | Alert.CANCEL, this, ClassalertListener, null, Alert.OK);
}
```

In the Alert Listener for the Alert, set the selectedIndex back to the original.

```
private function ClassalertListener(eventObj:CloseEvent):void 
{
            if (eventObj.detail==Alert.OK) 
            { adg1.selectedIndex = idindex; }
}
```